# Bounding box of predicted mask

Tags: python, mask, image-segmentation, bounding-box

I have an image segmentation problem. First I need to find a certain animal out of an image with multiple different animals. Then I need to find a certain feature in the animal. The first network build to find the particular animal is simply a unet doing binary classification. I have a resulting dice score of 96%.

Now I would like to be able to use the mask from the first network to crop the original image around the animal, I would also need to crop the second ground truth mask related to that image (this is the ground thruth for the features). How can I retreive a bounding box from the first mask predicted to be able to crop my images further?

I am coding in python and using pytorch and torchvision. I would like to avoid keras and tensorflow, any other library is welcome.

Comment: it sounds like your are trying to do something very close to mask-rcnn. check out their code and see how they apporaced the problem.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I had never seen this project before but it seems perfect for what I'm trying to acomplish

Comment: For anyone that would be asking the same question, I found this operation doable thanks to torchvision. Torchvision.ops has a function called mask_to_boxes. https://pytorch.org/vision/master/auto_examples/plot_repurposing_annotations.html